# Why is my table name being called twice in some cases but not in others? FastAPI, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using FastAPI which is Flask-like. I have 2 different pages, one which functions completely fine and the other which gives the following:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57256 - "GET /companies?month=4&year=2020&day=5 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 384, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 149, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 102, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 550, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 196, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 150, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File ".\main.py", line 73, in get_companies
    return myquery.all()
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3246, in all
    return list(self)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3405, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3430, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 984, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1097, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1287, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1481, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1247, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "c:\users\admin\google~1\python\new_co~1\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateAlias) table name "companies" specified more than once

[SQL: SELECT companies.record_created AS companies_record_created, companies.number AS companies_number, companies.name AS companies_name, companies.incorporated AS companies_incorporated
FROM companies, companies
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM companies.incorporated) = %(param_1)s AND EXTRACT(month FROM companies.incorporated) = %(param_2)s AND EXTRACT(day FROM companies.incorporated) = %(param_3)s]
[parameters: {'param_1': 2020, 'param_2': 4, 'param_3': 5}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

So the crux of the error is that the table name is being generated twice for some unknown reason.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateAlias) table name "companies" specified more than once
```

Which I can see here:

```
FROM companies, companies
```

This only happens in one version and not the other(?!).

Now let me show you something that works completely fine.

```
# main.py
# various imports

...


@app.get("/incorporated/today")
def read_cos_today(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    return crud.get_company_by_date(db, year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day).all()
```

The above works fine and returns the expected json.

The below however gives the error previously mentioned.

```
# main.py
# various imports

...


@app.get("/companies", response_model=List[schemas.Company])
def get_companies(
    year: int = None, month: int = None, day: int = None, number: int = None, 
    name: str = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    arguments = locals()
    arguments.pop("db")
    if not any(arguments.values()):
        return None
    myquery = db.query(models.Company)
    for key, value in arguments.items():
        if not value:
            continue
        if key == 'year' or key == 'month' or key == 'day':
            myquery = crud.get_company_by_date(db, query=myquery, **{key:value})
        else:
            myquery = crud.filter_query(myquery, **{key:value})
    return myquery.all()
```

and below are the functions in `crud.py`

```
# crud.py
# various imports

...


def filter_query(query: Query, **kwargs):
    """Filter an input query for the given kwargs.

    Args:
        query (Query): An existing query from the database.
        **kwargs: A column from the database.

    Returns:
        query (Query): The filtered query.
    """

    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        query = query.filter_by(**{key:value})
    return query


def get_company_by_date(session: Session, query: Query = None, **kwargs):
    """Return an ordered Company query object filtered by date.

    Args:
        session (Session): A session connected to the database.
        query (Query): An existing query from the database.
        **kwargs: year, month or day (int).

    Returns:
        query (Query): A query result filtered by the input kwargs.
    """

    if not query:
        query = session.query(models.Company)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print("Do the thing here yes")
        query = query.filter(extract(key, models.Company.incorporated)==value)
    return query
```

This is driving me a little bit mad. I can't understand why it would be duplicating the table name here. Even when I do a simple request of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies?month=4` it raises the error, so presumably it is not a problem with the way these are being chained(?).

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It seems like there are 2 separate classes `models.Company`, one seen by `get_companies` and the other by `get_company_by_date`.

Comment: If you're talking about `schemas.Company` and `models.Company` that is by design and is part of the way FastAPI separates front end and back end.

Comment: No, not schemas, but `models.Company`. The behaviour matches the case where there are 2 instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Bah. Apparently passing the existing query into `crud.get_company_by_date` is what's causing the issue.

In `main.py` I edited the `get_companies` function to the following (as the problem seems to be in chaining the `get_company_by_date` function):

```
@app.get("/companies", response_model=List[schemas.Company])
def get_companies(
    year: int = None, month: int = None, day: int = None, number: int = None, 
    name: str = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    arguments = locals()
    arguments.pop("db")

    if not any(arguments.values()):
        return None

    myquery = db.query(models.Company)
    datedict = {}

    for key, value in arguments.items():
        if key == "number" and datedict:
            myquery = crud.get_company_by_date(db, **datedict)

        if not value:
            continue

        if key == 'year' or key == 'month' or key == 'day':
            datedict[key] = value
        else:
            myquery = crud.filter_query(myquery, **{key:value})

    return myquery.all()
```